# What is the language called that specifies the syntax of a language or construct (even itself)

Tags: syntax

There is a language or expression or something that is used specifically to describe or specify the syntax of a language (natural or programming, but I think most often programming - even itself)

I seem to remember it has the basic lines of `this := that + the other` or something, where those components can be further specified: `that := what | not` and `the other := some thing | nothing | whatever` and so on...

What is this language (or if there are several, what are the most common ones)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form ?

Comment: Ah - I think I was remembering either Backus Naur or Extended Backus Naur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one of them is the Backus-Naur Form:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus-Naur_Form